# Pasting URLs That Have Been Scraped From a Webpage

Tags: vba

So I'm looking to dump a bunch of URLs from a webpage into excel as a list. I was previously dumping the items into a listbox, but I have found that listboxes are quite difficult to work with!

Once I have collected the URLs into a column in excel, I want excel to click on each link and find the email address that is on the page. Here is the coding that I currently have...

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

url_name = Sheet1.Range("A2")
If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub

IE.Navigate (url_name)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

Set AllHyperLinks = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks

Range("x":"F").Value = hyper_link
```

This is all I have so far! I'm not sure how to complete the loop! I want the code to paste every new URL that it finds on the page in the next empty row in column F.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete the loop in this way:

```
Dim IE As Object, LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
For i = 2 To LR
url_name = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value
If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub

IE.Navigate (url_name)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

Set AllHyperLinks = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks

Range("x":"F").Value = hyper_link

Next hyper_link
Next i
```

Please note that if you have large set of data, this is going to take a LOOOONGGGG time.